# C ++ cout and cin exercice Error: main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’

Tags: c++, error-handling, cin, cout

I am a complete beginner and I have been looking at this code for two days and I just cant figure out what I did that keeps creating this error message:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:19:43: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘const char [25]’)
  value of num1 =" << num1 >> "  and the value of num2 " << num2 >> ".";
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.tcc:1465:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.tcc:1465:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:19:46: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>’
 lue of num1 =" << num1 >> "  and the value of num2 " << num2 >> ".";
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //variable declaration
    int num1, num2, newNum, SECRET;
    SECRET = 11;
    double RATE = 12.50;
    string name;
    double hoursWorked, wages;

    //executable statements
    cout << "Give me two integers"; 
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << "The value of num1 =" << num1 >> "  and the value of num2 " << num2 >> ".";
    newNum = (num1*2)+num2;
    cout<< "The new value of newNum =" << newNum;
    newNum = newNum+ SECRET;
    cout<< "The new value of newNum =" << newNum;
    cout << "What's your last name?";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter a decimal number between 0 and 70";
    cin >> hoursWorked;
    wages = RATE*hoursWorked;
    cout << "Name: " << name << "\n" << "Pay Rate: $" << RATE << "\n" << "Hours Worked: "<<hoursWorked << "\n" << "Salary: $  " << wages;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```<< num1 >>``` should be ```<< num1 <<```

Comment: The above comment came _after_ the answer below that says the same thing. The comment got 3 helpful votes and the answer 1. Strange.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thx, we post pretty much at the same time tbh

Comment: @MartinMorterol Yes, but sometimes the explanation is that the answer isn't visible when people vote on comments - but you answer was visible when the comment appeared, which is why I found it a bit strange that your answer didn't get votes too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, question's answers are not visible in "/review/first-posts/" interface. It may be the reason.

Comment: @MaxV Yeah, could be. I rarely vote on comments via reviews myself but I guess that's entirely possible.

Comment: Comments and answers gave you the fix for your code. The fix for your learning is to carefully read what the compiler says. After years of writing code, I sometimes read too quickly some error messages and loose time in trying to fix the wrong thing. In your example the >> characters were pointed to be the problem, and the compiler told you that it was looking for a given operator that does not exist. A way to look for such mistakes if you still do not see where it comes from is to break your statement on several lines.

Answer (score 4):

You used the wrong operator :

```
// cout << "The value of num1 =" << num1 >> "  and the value of num2 " << num2 >> ".";  
//                                  here ^               and              here ^
```

You should have used :

```
cout << "The value of num1 =" << num1 << "  and the value of num2 " << num2 << ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

//variable declaration
int num1, num2, newNum, SECRET;
SECRET = 11;
double RATE = 12.50;
string name;
double hoursWorked, wages;

//executable statements
cout << "Give me two integers"; 
cin >> num1 >> num2;
cout << "The value of num1 =" << num1 << "  and the value of num2 " << num2 << ".";
newNum = (num1*2)+num2;
cout<< "The new value of newNum =" << newNum;
newNum = newNum+ SECRET;
cout<< "The new value of newNum =" << newNum;
cout << "What's your last name?";
cin >> name;
cout << "Enter a decimal number between 0 and 70";
cin >> hoursWorked;
wages = RATE*hoursWorked;
cout << "Name: " << name << "\n" << "Pay Rate: $" << RATE << "\n" << "Hours Worked: "<<hoursWorked << "\n" << "Salary: $  " << wages;
return 0;
}
```

Don't use ">>" in cout even if you are printing variable. That was a simple syntax error.